# How to create delta tables in ADLS Gen2 using spark local without Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I'm trying to read csv files from ADLS gen2 (Microsoft Azure) and create delta tables . I'm able to successfully initiate a sparksession and read the csv files via spark in my local. But when I'm trying to write the dataframe as delta table I'm getting error saying
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o120.save.
:org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaIllegalStateException: Versions (Vector(0, 0)) are not contiguous.

I've used all the combinations of different versions of spark, python and other related jars, but I'm still not able to create Delta tables from my local.

These are the configurations I've used to setup spark and read the data from ADLS gen2
Spark-3.3.0
Python-3.10
delta-spark-2.3
azure-storage-8.6.6
hadoop-azure-3.3.1
hadoop-azure-datalake-3.3.3
hadoop-common-3.3.3

**This the code I tried.**

```
   from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
        from delta.tables import *
        spark =SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.3.0")
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
        .config("spark.delta.logStore.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.S3SingleDriverLogStore")
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
        .config("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
        .config("spark.jars", r"C:\Users\Proem Sports\Documents\Jupyter notebooks\jars\mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar")
        .config("spark.jars", r"C:\Users\Proem Sports\Documents\Jupyter notebooks\jars\azure-storage-8.6.6.jar") 
        .config("spark.jars", r"C:\Users\Proem Sports\Documents\Jupyter notebooks\jars\hadoop-azure-3.3.1.jar")
        .config("spark.jars", r"C:\Users\Proem Sports\Documents\Jupyter notebooks\jars\hadoop-azure-datalake-3.3.3.jar")  
        .config("spark.jars", r"C:\Users\Proem Sports\Documents\Jupyter notebooks\jars\hadoop-common-3.3.3.jar")    
        .config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
        .config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
        .config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
        .config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
        .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "TRUE")
        .config("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "CORRECTED")
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", r"C:\Users\Proem Sports\Documents\Jupyter notebooks\Dev_scripts\metastore_db")
        .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
        .config("spark.delta.commitInfo.merge.enabled", "true")
        .config("fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization", "false")
        .config("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
        .config("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "SharedKey")
        .config("fs.azure.account.key.proemdatalake.blob.core.windows.net", "account-key")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate()
        spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type."+storage_account_name+".dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
        spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type."+storage_account_name+".dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
        spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id."+storage_account_name+".dfs.core.windows.net", client_id)
        spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret."+storage_account_name+".dfs.core.windows.net", client_secret)
        spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint."+storage_account_name+".dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+directory_id+"/oauth2/token")

        df=spark.read.format("csv").load("abfss://"container_name"@"storage_account_name".dfs.core.windows.net/RAW_DATA/MERHCHANDISE/MERCH_20230424_.csv",header=True,inferSchema=True)

df.write.format("delta").option("overwriteSchema", "true").option('delta.columnMapping.mode', 'name').save("abfss://"container_name"@"storage_account_name".dfs.core.windows.net/tables/delta_table1")
```

**And the error I'm gettin is:**
`{Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o120.save. : org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaIllegalStateException: Versions (Vector(0, 0)) are not contiguous. at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaErrorsBase.deltaVersionsNotContiguousException(DeltaErrors.scala:852) at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaErrorsBase.deltaVersionsNotContiguousException$(DeltaErrors.scala:850) at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaErrors$.deltaVersionsNotContiguousException(DeltaErrors.scala:2293)}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AzureLogstore` while doing config.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.3.0")\
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .config("spark.delta.logStore.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.AzureLogStore") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "4g") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "4g") \
    .config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED") \
    .config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED") \
    .config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED") \
    .config("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED") \
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "TRUE") \
    .config("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "CORRECTED") \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", r"C:\Users\v-jgs\Desktop\warehouse") \
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true") \
    .config("spark.delta.commitInfo.merge.enabled", "true") \
    .config("fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization", "false") \
    .config("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem") \
    .config("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "SharedKey") \
    .config("fs.azure.account.key.<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "account_key") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

and

[image]

So change it to azure log store.

```
.config("spark.delta.logStore.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.AzureLogStore")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working, Please let me know while we are creating Delta tables where we will be storing the meta data of that table. I'm looking for a way where my laptop would only be the server to run the job, Rest everything including logs and meta data will be stored in Azure account.

Comment: All delta logs will be stored in storage account after successful write to the adls path.
You confirm that by again read the table with same path.